# file handling : displaying content within comment/quotes

Tags: c++, file-handling

I'm writing a C++ program to show any text within quotes or single line or multi line comment in a text file. The problem is that I can;t get it to run properly. This is my program:

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <fstream.h>
#include <string.h>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;

int main () {
    char ch, name[20];
    int count=0;
    fstream fin;
    cin>>name;
    fin.open(file_name, ios::in);
    while(!fin.eof()) {
        fin.get(ch);
        if(ch=='/') {
            fin.get(ch);
            if(ch=='*') { 
                a:
                fin.get(ch);
                while(ch!='*') {
                    cout<<ch;
                    fin.get(ch);
                }
                fin.get(ch);
                if(ch!='/') goto a;                                 
            }
            if(ch=='/') {
                fin.get(ch);
                while(ch!='\n') {
                    cout<<ch;
                    fin.get(ch);              
                }
            }
        }
    }

    getch(); 
    return 0;
}
```

edit : It gets caught in infinite loop. idk how.
problem persists. I'm using Dev C++ editor.

Comment: not a solution to your specific problem, but instead of declaring `name` as a raw array of `char`s, declare it a `string` to avoid possible overflow

Comment: What does it mean you can't get it to run properly?  What input does it fail on?  What does it produce on that input?

Comment: That label/goto can easily be replaced by a loop, which is a lot better.

Answer (score 0):

An infinite loop requires a loop. You have two loops in your code. The first one `while(!fin.eof()) {` won't cause infinite looping because the file will eventually be exhasuted.

So we remain with the inner loop and the goto statement.
I think there is a bug in the logic - if there is never a slash after an asterik, the loop will never end.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've looked into it again and again. Even if there is a slash after an asterisk, it prints infinite slashes.